# Proving a hypothetical syllogism in Strong Kleene 3-valued Logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to show something similar to a deduction theorem, where:

{Γ&P}⊨Q ⇒ {Γ}⊨P→Q

We know that {Γ&P}⊨Q. Γ is our set of basic assumptions, P is acting as an auxiliary assumption in my attempt to prove the conditional from Γ.

We can prove that:

P→(Γ&P) [from the functional profile of the conjunction in strong Kleene, and Γ as our set of basic assumptions.]

We can prove that:

(Γ&P)→Q [as we know that {Γ&P}⊨Q (although I am also struggling for this part of the proof as well)]

So, if we have: P→(Γ&P) and (Γ&P)→Q

We should be able to prove that: P→Q

But I am unsure of this proof from (P→(Γ&P))&((Γ&P)→Q) to P→Q

---

Edit: I have looked at the truth tables and found the following:
[image: Table1]

The light green represents all lines where P1⊨Γ&P1 (Γ in the table = L)
The dark green represents all lines where Γ&P1⊨P2.

It seems that there are two lines (3.2 and 3.3) where Γ&P1⊨P2 but (Γ&P1)→P2 fails.

Comment: Do you really mean $\vDash$ rather than $\vdash$? In that case what you want to prove follows quite directly from the definition of $\vDash$. _Each_ of $\Gamma, P\vDash Q$ and $\Gamma\vDash P\to Q$ is true exactly if every valuation that satisfies $\Gamma$ and $P$ also satisfies $Q$. Since the two claims are true under exactly the same conditions, one implies the other.

Comment: I figured If I proved if in ⊨, I can just convert to ⊢ with the completeness of K3. @Henning Makholm That is also a massive help - I'll have a look at the tables for each.